# Hello guys I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, but I'm having the issue with connecting to my database and querying data

Tags: mysql, node.js, config, web-development-server, querying

```
Listening...
(node:2769) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1138:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:454:10)
    at Connection.query (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:196:8)
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.query (internal/util.js:296:12)
    at Object.query (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/core/DBConnection.js:22:6)
    at Object.exports.getCustomerFromUsername (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/core/CustomerAuthDB.js:110:35)
(node:2769) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2769) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2769) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:212:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Connection.query (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.query (internal/util.js:296:12)
    at Object.query (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/core/DBConnection.js:22:6)
    at Object.exports.getCustomerFromUsername (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/core/CustomerAuthDB.js:110:35)
    at Object.exports.createCustomer (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/core/CustomerAuthDB.js:119:20)
    at Object.exports.post [as /api/auth/customer/create-account] (/home/shpham6/db-team-13/api/auth/customer/create-account.js:4:32)
(node:2769) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

I've looked everywhere and changed my db-connection-info.js to have the "host" : "127.0.0.1" but this didn't help at all. I also tried to reinstall mysql hoping that this may solve any connection issues, since it was working before messing with the mysql database.

Comment: Ensure MySQL is actually running and listening on port 3306, and your local firewall isn't blocking it.

Comment: Try `telnet localhost 3306` to test if your MySql server accept connections on port 3306